# How to get rows and count of rows simultaneously

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that returns `rows` and `count` simultaneously.

I tried following `ADO.net` code but I get `IndexOutOfRange` Exception on ItemCount(ItemCount contains `count` of rows)

```
 public List<Product> GetProductDetails(Product p)
 {
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[usp_Get_ServerPagedProducts]", con);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rvcName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = p.Name;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rvcCode", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = p.Code;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@riProductTypeID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = p.ProductTypeID;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ristartIndex", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = p.RowIndex;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rimaxRows", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = p.PageSize;
      con.Open();
      using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           Product product = new Product(reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Code"].ToString(), reader["Description"].ToString(), (DateTime)reader["DateCreated"], Convert.ToInt32(reader["ProductID"]), Convert.ToInt32(reader["ProductTypeID"]), reader["ProductTypeName"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(reader["ItemCount"]));
           products.Add(product);
        }
      }
    }     
    return products;
 }
```

The Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT ProductID,
       Name,
       [Description],
       Code,
       DateCreated,
       ProductTypeID,
       ProductTypeName
FROM (
    SELECT P.pkProductID AS ProductID,
           P.Name AS Name,
           P.[Description] AS [Description],
           P.Code AS Code,
           P.DateCreated AS DateCreated,
           P.fkProductTypeID AS ProductTypeID,
           PT.Name AS ProductTypeName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.pkProductID) AS RowNumber
    FROM Product P
    INNER JOIN ProductType PT ON PT.pkProductTypeID = P.fkProductTypeID
    WHERE P.Name LIKE '%' + @rvcName + '%'
        AND P.Code LIKE '%' + @rvcCode + '%'
        AND (@riProductTypeID = 0 OR P.fkProductTypeID = @riProductTypeID)
) AS tblProduct
WHERE RowNumber >= @ristartIndex
    AND RowNumber < (@ristartIndex + @rimaxRows)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
FROM (
    SELECT P.pkProductID,
           P.Name,
           P.[Description],
           P.Code,
           P.DateCreated,
           P.fkProductTypeID AS 'ProductTypeID',
           PT.Name AS 'ProductTypeName',
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Name DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Product P
    INNER JOIN ProductType PT ON PT.pkProductTypeID = P.fkProductTypeID
    WHERE P.Name LIKE '%' + @rvcName + '%'
        AND P.Code LIKE '%' + @rvcCode + '%'
        AND (@riProductTypeID = 0 OR P.fkProductTypeID = @riProductTypeID)
) AS TotalCount
```

Is it because its returning two tables? What's the solution?

Comment: So you have two resultsets: the first with the actual rows and the second with the row count, is that right? Can't you create a counter in the while loop or to use the [SqlDataReader.NextResult method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Btw, if your table columns allow `NULL` values, I would change that `.ToString()` by ` as string ?? ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `NextResult` if you return multiple recordsets:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
        product.Code = reader["Code"].ToString();
        // ...
        products.Add(product);
    }
    if (reader.NextResult() && reader.Read())
    {
        int itemCount = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ItemCount"));
        foreach(Product p in products)
            p.ItemCount = itemCount;
    }
}
```

But in my opinion it would be better to include the total-count in the first query. Then it's simpler and you don't need the final loop. The database can cope with such sub-queries. The optimizer will ensure that it gets executed only once if it's not a correlated subquery.

Comment: When Im returning the `List` it sets `ItemCount` to 0

Comment: @HumaAli: have you used the debugger? Set a breakpoint at `int itemCount = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ItemCount"));`. What happens?

Comment: At this point the ItemCount is set to the value. But on line `return products` line it becomes 0

Comment: @HumaAli: that's not possible. `Product` is a reference type and you change every product in the loop: `foreach(Product p in products)
            p.ItemCount = itemCount;`. So the list should contain products with the correct `ItemCount`.

Comment: @HumaAli: but you say `return product` not `return products`. Whas that a typo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102457/discussion-between-huma-ali-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 0):

Check the column name that is being returned by your stored procedure. It is probably typoed or something other than "ItemCount".

As per the documentation for [SqlDataReader.Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and IndexOutOfRange exception is thrown in the case where no column with the specified name was found.

Comment: No no spelling mistake. I have posted the `sp` as well in my question.